# Is it possible to give a system app full read and write access to the main external storage in Android 11?

Tags: custom-roms, system-apps, file-permissions

We're building our own ROM from AOSP, and the ROM will have a third-party app installed to `/system/priv-app` but we need to give that app read and write access to the main external storage without any user input.

The ROM is based on Android 11, API level 30.

However, we found no such permissions that could allow us to grant the app external storage access, and it seems like whatever permissions like `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, etc. either have no effect or doesn't function as expected in Android 11.

We found `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but this also needs user input via `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` intent.

Are there any hidden permissions to allow us such thing? Or is there any other solution that can achieve the same effect?